# Splitting Error in string data using python

Tags: python, regex, split

Hi I want to split the below string. But I got the error in spliitng

```
import string

description = "ABC:PUNE COLLEGE XYZ:SATARA COLLEGE TTC ACCT KOREGAON SATARA PQR: MUMBAI TTC ACCT NUMBER 45767"

tag_list = ["ABC:", "XYZ:", "TTC ACCT", "PQR:", "TTC ACCT NUMBER"]

for each_tag in tag_list:
    if each_tag[-1] is not ":":
        description = description.replace(each_tag, each_tag + ":")
print(description)

tag_list_formatted = ["ABC:", "XYZ:", "TTC ACCT:", "PQR:", "TTC ACCT NUMBER:"]

for each_new_tag in tag_list_formatted:
    description = description.replace(each_new_tag, "|" + each_new_tag)

print(description)
```

Please Check the below Expected Output

```
Expected Output :-
"|ABC:PUNE COLLEGE |XYZ:SATARA COLLEGE |TTC ACCT: KOREGAON SATARA |PQR: MUMBAI |TTC ACCT NUMBER: 45767"
```

Please Check the below Error Output

```
Error Output :-
"|ABC:PUNE COLLEGE |XYZ:SATARA COLLEGE |TTC ACCT: KOREGAON SATARA |PQR: MUMBAI |TTC ACCT: NUMBER 45767"
```

How can i solve the above error using python?
Please check the `|TTC ACCT: NUMBER` in Error Output. But I Want to `|TTC ACCT NUMBER:` Output.

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: What is difference between error output and Excepted output

Comment: @ravishankarchavare Please check the `|TTC ACCT: NUMBER` in Error Output and check the `|TTC ACCT NUMBER:` in Expected Output

Comment: @user5173426 Please check the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the python replace look like this `str.replace(old, new[, max])`

**old** − This is old substring to be replaced.

**new** − This is new substring, which would replace old substring.

**max** − If this optional argument max is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

In your case you have this tag `TTC ACCT` and this `TTC ACCT NUMBER` when you replace without specifying tha `max` the first `TTC ACCT` will be `TTC ACCT:` and then `TTC ACCT NUMBER` will be `TTC ACCT : NUMBER` and that why you see `TTC ACCT: NUMBER 45767`

Make this line :

```
description = description.replace(each_tag, each_tag + ":")
```

like this :

```
description = description.replace(each_tag, each_tag + ":" ,1)
```

## Get the following code :

```
import string

description = "ABC:PUNE COLLEGE XYZ:SATARA COLLEGE TTC ACCT KOREGAON SATARA PQR: MUMBAI TTC ACCT NUMBER 45767"

tag_list = ["ABC:", "XYZ:", "TTC ACCT", "PQR:", "TTC ACCT NUMBER"]

for each_tag in tag_list:
   if each_tag[-1] is not ":":
       description = description.replace(each_tag, each_tag + ":" ,1)

print(description)

tag_list_formatted = ["ABC:", "XYZ:", "TTC ACCT:", "PQR:", "TTC ACCT NUMBER:"]
for each_new_tag in tag_list_formatted:
    description = description.replace(each_new_tag, "|" + each_new_tag)

print(description)
```

**Output:**

```
|ABC:PUNE COLLEGE |XYZ:SATARA COLLEGE |TTC ACCT: KOREGAON SATARA |PQR: MUMBAI |TTC ACCT NUMBER: 45767
```

Comment: Please Post you complete code. Please check the my code

Comment: @Akshay did you test it?

Comment: @Akshay wait , just copy my code and test it , make sure there is no  unexpected indent